# Making network drive share accessible from Android device and part of its media library

Tags: networking

I would like my Android devices to be able to play music that's stored on a Windows PC's network shared drive.

The important thing to me is that the Android device not only be able to access the network share (I know there are lots of apps that will do this), but that the Android operating system consider the music files on the network share to be included in its media library database. Most music playing apps use the device's official media library database as the source of available music.

I am not interested in suggestions for media playing apps that will play from a network share. I want to be able to use ANY music playing app that uses the Android media library, so I am only interested in solutions that will actually affect the media library database.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly what you want but ES file explorer has its own network tab that you can access shares on PC and stream media to android device. You can make favorites from them and name music for that matter. If you want you can install Kodi app to android and from there you can make local music and network music into one big mash up/hybrid library - i think that would do the trick. More on Kodi: https://kodi.tv/